# Laravel how to "properly" store & retrieve models in a Redis hash

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm developing a Laravel application & started using Redis as a caching system. I'm thinking of caching the data of all of a specific model I have, as a user may make an API request that this model is involved in quite often. Would a valid solution be storing each model in a hash, where the field is that record's unique ID, and the values are just the unique model's data, or is this use case too complicated for a simple key value database like Redis? I"m also curious as to how I would create model instances from the hash, when I retrieve all the data from it. Replies are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: Yes**, you can store a model, or collections, or basically anything in the key-value caching of Redis. As long as the key provided is unique and can be retraced. Redis could even be used as a primary database.

**Long answer**

Ultimately, I think it depends on the implementation. There is a lot of optimization that can be done before someone can/should consider caching **all models**. For "simple" records that involve large datasets, I would advise to first optimize your queries and code and check the results. Examples:

1. Select only data you need, not entire models.
2. Use the [Database Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) for interacting with the database when targeting large records, rather than [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) (Eloquent is significantly slower due to the Active Record pattern).
3. Consider using the `toBase()` method. This retrieves all data but does not create the Eloquent model, saving precious resources.
4. Use tools like the [Laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)  to analyze and discover potential long query loads.

For large datasets that do not change often or optimization is not possible anymore: caching is the way to go!

There is no right answer here, but maybe this helps you on your way! There are plenty of [packages](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching) that implement similar behaviour.